# Android ScrollView invisible Custom View

Tags: java, android, layout, graphics, scrollview

I have a custom view which I put in ScrollView like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.test.view android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

I have implemented onDraw() and many other methods in my custom view, also onMeasure:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(600, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

And then when I start the application, I get many logs from the onDraw() method, and the TouchEvent is ok handled, but I don't see My custom View. It seems it's there, but as if it is invisible...

Maybe I am missing something ... ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The Custom View is nothing special, just a View that shows Bitmap:

```
private class myView extends View{

 public myView(Context context) {
  super(context);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.packagebm);
  canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);
  Log.i("myview", "onDraw()");
 }

@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(300, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

    }
  }
```

Comment: what should it look like? perhaps post the full code from your view

Comment: does it make a difference if you get rid of the scrollview?

Comment: <_< yes, cause I want the View to be in ScrollView..

Comment: I mean does it display any differently?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `setMeasuredDimension` in your custom view's onMeasure. So it should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, height);
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, resolveSize(600, heightMeasureSpec));
}
```

Comment: in case if I put custom view in scrollView it simply onSizeChanged() and onDraw() not called for view...any suggestion?